# Uniqueness constraint on other columns in table of foreign key

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, unique-constraint

I have some **Thing**s that have 0-* names in any number of *language*s:

```
CREATE TABLE Things(
    thing_id INT PRIMARY_KEY,
    thing_proprty INT);

CREATE TABLE ThingNames(
    thing_name_id INT PRIMARY_KEY,
    thing_id INT,
    language CHAR[2],
    name VARCHAR[64] UNIQUE,
    FOREIGN KEY (thing_id) REFERENCES Things(thing_id));
```

The things are relevant in a number of **Field**s, and in each field they have 0-1 **CanonicalName**s per language. The straightforward way is

```
CREATE TABLE Fields(
    field_id INT PRIMARY_KEY,
    name VARCHAR[64])

CREATE TABLE CanonicalNames(
    thing_id INT
    field_id INT
    canonical_name_id INT
    FOREIGN KEY (thing_id) REFERENCES Things(thing_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (field_id) REFERENCES Fields(field_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (canonical_name_id) REFERENCES ThingNames(thing_name_id));
```

But this misses the 0-1 constraint, which would be a uniqueness constraint on *field_id* together with the *thing_id* and *language* columns of ThingNames as referenced by *canonical_name_id*. Including all columns as foreign keys in CanonicalNames is of course redundant and error prone, so is there a way to impose uniqueness constraints across tables? Or is there a better solution here that I am not seeing?

Comment: Do you mean UNIQUE(thing_id,name) in ThingNames?

Comment: Not quite. Since a thing may have 0-* names per language but only 0-1 canonical names per field and language, I can't impose the uniqueness constraint in ThingNames.

Comment: Sample data would really help explain the relationships.  A database tag would also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure about a couple of things in your design. Declaring ThingNames.name as key means that the same thing can't have the same name in two different languages, but that seems likely to happen with related languages (e.g. Norwegian and Danish), or when technical terms are left untranslated.

And the concept of relevance isn't explicitly represented in your schema. Is a Thing relevant to a Field only if it has at least one Canonical Name (for some language)?

However, making some assumptions, I'd suggest this model (Dataphor-based pseudocode, data types omitted):

```
create table Thing {
  ThingId,
  ThingProperty,
  key { ThingID }
};

create table Field {
  FieldId,
  FieldName,
  key { FieldId },
  key { FieldName } // Assumption - or can several Fields have the same name?
};

create table Relevance { // Standard many-to-many association table
  ThingId,
  FieldId,
  key { ThingId, FieldId },
  reference Relevance_Thing { ThingId } references Thing { ThingId },
  reference Relevance_Field { FieldId } references Field { FieldId }
};

create table ThingName {
  ThingName,
  Language,
  ThingId,
  key { ThingName, Language }, // Assuming the same thing may have the same name in different languages
  reference ThingName_Thing { ThingId } references Thing { ThingId }
};

create table CanonicalName {
  ThingId,
  FieldId,
  Language,
  CanonicalName,
  key { ThingId, FieldId, Language },
  reference CanonicalName_Relevance { ThingId, FieldId } references Relevance { ThingId, FieldId },
  reference CanonicalName_ThingName { ThingId, Language, CanonicalName } references ThingName { ThingId, Language, ThingName }
};
```

CanonicalName isn't in BCNF, because of the FD `{ Canonicalname, Language } -> { ThingId }`, but the redundancy is controlled by the reference CanonicalName_ThingName. (You could call it a foreign key, but it is actually a foreign superkey.) This is not a bug, it's how you ensure that the canonical name is one of the thing names. (I'm assuming that is a rule.) In this design, having a Language column in CanonicalName isn't redundant, and it enables the 0-1 constraint you're missing.

This design allows multiple Things to have the same name in different languages, but also allows different Things to have the same name in different languages. For instance, "kjole" means "dress" both in Norwegian and Danish, but "dress" in Norwegian means "suit" in English. Let me know if this should be disallowed, and I'll update the design.

The Relevance table may (or perhaps should) be omitted if there is a rule saying that a Thing is relevant to a Field if and only if it has at least one Canonical Name for that Field. Then CanonicalName would have to reference Field instead of Relevance, of course.

Comment: Relevance is handled in another way that is orthogonal to this problem, but you're right that a uniqueness constraint on thing names is too strict. Apart from that, what you're suggesting is essentially that my premise is false and that controlled redundancy (I maintain that it is redundancy since it does not tell me anything I don't already know from canonical_name_id) is acceptable and perhaps even necessary. I'm prepared to accept this as an answer, but if anyone else has alternative views I'm all ears.

Comment: Yes, CanonicalName.ThingId is redundant, as I (perhaps indirectly) state, but it is needed for the key constraint that ensures at most one canonical name per thing, field and language, as well as for the foreign superkey that ensures that the canonical name is one of the thing names. A redundancy-free schema would have to enforce these rules using far more complicated constraints, which SQL DBMSs typically don't support. It's a trade-off, but redundancy controlled by foreign superkeys is often the most practical solution.